# Package an app with Shoes under Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, shoes

I'm trying to create a self-running standalone .exe package using [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com). When I launch Shoes.exe and click on "Package an App with Shoes" nothing happens, but I get the following error in the console:

```
126: The specified module could not be found. - C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/i386-mingw32/binject.so
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/shoes/app_package.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/shoes.rb:206:in `app_package'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Shoes/3.2.14-gtk2-32/lib/shoes.rb:171:in `block (4 levels) in splash'
-e:1:in `call'
```

This is on Windows7x64, running Shoes v3.2.14. Is there a know problem with the packager, and if so is there any workaround?

This file does exist on my hard drive:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Shoes\3.2.14-gtk2-32\lib\ruby\2.1.0\i386-mingw32\binject.so`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [a bug in Shoes v3.2.14](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/issues/265). It [has been fixed in v3.2.15](https://github.com/ccoupe/shoes/commit/828698bf379c43fcea1ed29353f5dedd4f55212d).

The workaround for v3.2.14 is the Shoes on other OS (e.g. OS X) is able to package a binary for Windows.